# Email sent from apex class contains incorrect Product value

Tags: apex, soql

I want to send an opportunity owner an email if they have an opportunity, that has a product attached where the;

```
Opportunity_owner_notification__c = False
AND
Active = False
AND
Record Type = Unavailable R&D Service
OR
Record Type = Unavailable R&D Project
```

And then update those product records where an email notification has been sent, so that another message is not sent in future.

What I am finding is that an email is being sent where the Opportunity contains a product meeting the criteria above, but it's not necessarily showing the correct product. For instance an opportunity may contain five products, 1 of which meets the criteria above, but the email is displaying the incorrect product. How can I ensure the email contains the correct product?

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        sendEmailtoOppOwner();
    }

    public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
    {
        List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
        listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, Owner.FirstName, (SELECT Id, Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems LIMIT 1)
                           FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In
                           (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = FALSE
                            AND Product2.Isactive = FALSE
                            AND (Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' OR Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Project' ))];

        for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity)
        {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
                mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
            for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)                
                mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + oppLineItem.Product2.Name);
                String body = 'Hi '+ opp.Owner.FirstName + ', ';     
                body += '<br><br>Salesforce recognises you as the owner of the following opportunity:'+ opp.Name;
            for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)
                body += '<br><br>Attached to this opportunity is a former R&D service or project that is no longer available:' + oppLineItem.Product2.Name;
                body += '<br><br> Please use the link below to view the opportunity record:';
                body += '<br><br>test.salesforce.com/'+ opp.id;     
                mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

                    update listOpportunity;
         }
Map<Id, Product2> products = new Map<Id, Product2>();
for(Opportunity opp: listOpportunity) {
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem: opp.opportunitylineitems) {
        products.put(oppLineItem.Product2Id, new Product2(Id=oppLineItem.Product2Id, Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c=true));
        }
    }
                    update products.values();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to modify your SOQL query and include your where clause twice

```
 listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, Owner.FirstName, (SELECT Id, Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems WHERE Product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = FALSE
                            AND Product2.Isactive = FALSE
                            AND (Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' OR Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Project' ) LIMIT 1)
                           FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In
                           (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = FALSE
                            AND Product2.Isactive = FALSE
                            AND (Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' OR Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Project' ))];
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much, that works! Just for my own knowledge, am I right thinking that what you've done by adding two WHERE clauses means that we only pull through the specific product records from the opportunity line items, whereas before we'd pull through a whole opportunity where any opportunity line item met the product critieria, meaning that if 1 record met the criteria, it would still pull through all of the op line items. So what you've done means we're pulling records at a more granular level?

Comment: In the previous case you have pulled an opportunity which might have correct product line item but you didn't selected that correct product line item. You were selected any product line item from an opportunity which has the product you need